# Debian Jessie with 2 Displays

Tags: debian, nvidia, graphics, display, multi-monitor

I have a Lenovo W540 with a NVIDIA Graphic Card:

```
[    0.000000] Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
[    0.383307] vgaarb: setting as boot device: PCI:0000:00:02.0
[    0.383308] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.383313] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:01:00.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=none,locks=none
[    0.383313] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.383314] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:01:00.0
[    0.383315] vgaarb: no bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[    2.296882] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    2.322942] VGA switcheroo: detected Optimus DSM method \_SB_.PCI0.PEG_.VID_ handle
[    2.329487] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    4.836856] vga_switcheroo: enabled

[    4.991385] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    4.997334] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
NVRM: nouveau, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv 
NVRM: was loaded and obtained ownership of the NVIDIA device(s).
NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
[    4.997338] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
```

When i use 1920 x 1200 (16:10) i can work with one display well but when i attach a second Display the resolution changes to 1024x768 (4:3) on both Displays. I tried Display Managers like lightdm but without luck.

I don't install the original nvidia driver because i have a lot of trouble with it in the past.

What can i do ? Is it possible to use two displays with Debian Jessie?

Comment: What says your Xorg log file?